# How can I make my Flutter app work also as a module app?

Tags: flutter

I've created a Flutter standalone app and it's all working fine.
But now I want to integrate some of the screens of that Flutter app in an existing Android/iOS app.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**.

I could make it work by adding this at the end of the pubspec.yaml:

```
module:
  androidPackage: com.teste.embeded
  iosBundleIdentifier: com.teste.embeded
```

Add this and then call a *packages get*. This will create 2 hidden folders in your project structure: .android and .ios.

**Becareful with the identation!** This settings must be inside the `flutter:` tag, like this:

```
flutter:  
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
    - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  module:
    androidPackage: com.test.embeded
    iosBundleIdentifier: com.test.embeded
```

After doing this, follow the documentation for the Android/iOS sides (skip the module creating parts).

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

Comment: what is this packagename 'com.teste.embeded', is that needs to replace with my package name?, or its a fixed package for adding as module. Thank you

Comment: Yes, use your own package!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The two hidden folders was created but inside them is not correct. For example, the new-created module's `.android' has an `app` folder, but mine doesn't have it.

Comment: Please add `androidX: true` also under the `module` .

Comment: When running `flutter build aar`, be sure to remove the `android` folder in your app, otherwise, the command will fail. You can check into a new git branch and delete your app's android folder before building Android Archive. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in tow ways:
1- Convert your project to Flutter module and then put that along side the native project and call your FlutterActivity from native
2- Convert your project to Flutter module and make an AAR from it ant import in the native project

Read this Flutter documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup