# How do you convert an Flutter project into a Flutter module?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I'm attempting to create an add-to-app (add2app) project with a native Android project and my existing Flutter project. I'd like to convert my existing Flutter project into a module so that it can be used with the add-to-app process. I've been referencing this documentation on creating new Flutter modules, however I can't seem to find any information on converting an existing Flutter project into a module.

Is there a way to convert an existing project into a module or is the expected process to copy all the files to a new module?

Best,

KienDA
I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952251/3003823

But after pub get, the content in .android and .ios folder is not correct, and I can not build aar successfully.

I want fully convert flutter app to flutter module in flutter